# How can I integrate a Toolbar

Tags: java, android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I'm trying to integrate a Toolbar to my existing App. I have the problem that in every tutorial I've found they're using a class like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

But I do already have a public class with an 'extends' in it. And as you know, in Java I can not extend two things in one class.

So: how can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need to extend AppCompatActivity to use a Toolbar.

Comment: You can't add toolbar to  class, you can just add it to **activity** or **fragment** or a **custom view**

Comment: I'm a beginner, sorry. What would I have to put where in my code?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most interesting reasons for moving from ActionBar to Toolbar was to make Toolbar a flexible widget that can be used anywhere in the layouts. You can add a Toolbar to your XML layout file like any other widgets (Button, TextView etc.). I don't know what you are trying to make or do, So as to give a better suggestion. But, As a solution to your question, simply add these lines to your XML layout and that will do it:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Make sure to have Support library dependency in your build.gradle.

Comment: First; thank you! It doesn't show any error but if I want to start the app, it blinks up for half a second or so then finishes it with an info window on my phone. Android Studio doesn't show any errors. May I send you the whole code?

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the toolbar, though I would like to see your code, if it's possible.

Comment: Please look in my other question post, named 'Adding a Toolbar doesn't work'